# Is it possible to use "Cover" as page number in PDF using Acrobat?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I know that we can create a "Cover" as page number in PDF for example using TeX.

But for an existing PDF file, is it possible to change a page number to the text "Cover"? I have Acrobat installed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the name of the pages in Adobe Acrobat Pro and use custom words instead of numbers only. You can also rename and adjust all the sections' page name independently if you want.

---

In Acrobat Pro, open your preference panels and go in the "Page Display" options.

**Check the box "Use Logical page Numbers"**

[image: How to change preferences in Acrobat pro Adobe]

**Then save this, and go right-click on the page you want to name "cover"; you will see the option to "Number Pages." Select it.**

Then change the prefix to the name you want. If you only want the word, use "None" in the scrolldown menu for the style.

If you want a number next to each page name, select the style you want. You'll get something like "cover1, cover2, etc."

[image: How to change page numbers in Acrobat Pro]

Comment: That is what I have been trying to find this whole afternoon! Thanks!